# Salesforce-bulk authentication issue

Tags: authentication, python, bulk

I'm trying to login using the Bulk API with the Python interface salesforce-bulk by:

```
bulk = salesforce_bulk.SalesforceBulk(username=userName, password=p)
```

This gives an error

```
AssertionError: Couldn't find location.href expression in page https://eu4.salesforce.com/_ui/identity/verification/method/EmailVerificationFinishUi/e?...
.
.
.
...(Username or password is wrong)
```

and sends me the email "Verify your identity in Salesforce":

```
You recently logged in to Salesforce from a device we don't recognize.

Browser: Unknown
Operating System: Unknown
.
.
To ensure your account's security, we need to verify your identity. Enter the following code where prompted by Salesforce.

Verification Code: xx
.
.
```

Obviously that doesn't work as I'm not using a browser. How to get along with this? Should the email verification be turned off in Salesforce or is there another workaround?

Comment: try to add security token with password.